# Is there a way to rotate the ticklabels in a ternary plot with the python ternary package?

Tags: python, ternary

I am working with the python ternary [package](https://github.com/marcharper/python-ternary). To improve the intuitive understanding of the plot, I want to rotate the tick labels on the axis to indicate in which direction the gridlines of this axis point, like in the plot below.

[image]

Python-ternary produces this result with the following code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import ternary

figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
tax = ternary.TernaryAxesSubplot(ax=ax, scale=100)

# draw Boundary and Gridlines
tax.boundary(linewidth=2.0)
tax.gridlines(color="black", multiple=10)

# ticks settings
tax.ticks(
    axis='lbr',
    linewidth=1,
    multiple=20,
    offset=0.02,
    fontsize=12
)

# remove mpl axes
tax.get_axes().axis('off')
tax.clear_matplotlib_ticks()
ternary.plt.show()
```

[image]

what I have tried so far is

- tax.ticks(axis='b',rotation=45)
- tax.ticks(axis='b',labelrotation=45)
- tax.ticks(axis='b').set_rotation(45)

without success. any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cheap solution was of course just hack the tick labels in as annotations, which can be rotated with the *rotation* argument. not very elegant, but it solves the problem for now

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import ternary

fs = 16

figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
tax = ternary.TernaryAxesSubplot(ax=ax, scale=100)

# draw Boundary and Gridlines
tax.boundary(linewidth=2.0)
tax.gridlines(color="black", multiple=10)

# define tick locations
tick_locs = range(10, 100, 10)

# add left ticks 
for i in tick_locs:
    tax.annotate(
        text=str(i),
        position=[-10, 100-i +2, 90],
        rotation=300,
        fontsize=fs
    )
    # add tick lines
    tax.line(
        [-3 , i+3, 90],
        [0 , i, 90],
        color='k'
    )
    
# add bottom ticks 
for i in tick_locs:
    tax.annotate(
        text=str(i),
        position=[i - 2, -10, 90],
        rotation=60,
        fontsize=fs
    )
    # add tick lines
    tax.line(
        [i , -3, 90],
        [i , 0, 90],
        color='k'
    )

# add right ticks
for i in tick_locs:
    tax.annotate(
        text=str(i),
        position=[105-i, i-2, 0],
        rotation=0,
        fontsize=fs
    )
    # add tick lines
    tax.line(
        [100-i , i, 0],
        [103-i , i, 0],
        color='k'
    )

# remove mpl axes
tax.clear_matplotlib_ticks()
ternary.plt.show()
```